# Computing $H_i(\mathbb{RP}^n \times \mathbb{RP^m}; G)$

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

I'm trying to compute $H_i(\mathbb{RP}^n \times \mathbb{RP}^m; G)$ for $G = \mathbb{Z}, \mathbb{Z_2}$ respectively by using the cellular chain complexes.

I'm not really sure how to get started, though I do know each real projective space has 1 cell in each dimension up to its dimension. I also know that the chain complex for $\mathbb{RP}^n$ should look like:

$\rightarrow 0 \rightarrow G \rightarrow G \rightarrow \ldots \rightarrow G \rightarrow 0$ where $G$ is repeated $n$ times as a result of the projective plane having 1 cell in each dimension up to its dimension.

Comment: Is that an $m$ or an $n$ in the title? Do you know the Kunneth formula?

Comment: Sorry I edited the typo in the question. Also I'm supposed to do it from scratch just using the cellular chain-complexes and boundary maps I think? At least that's what the wording of the question suggests to me. - This question is from Hatcher

Comment: When I tried to compute the chain complexes on a special case $C_*(\mathbb{RP}^3 \times \mathbb{RP}^2)$ for my chain complexes I got: $ 0 \rightarrow G \rightarrow G^2 \rightarrow G^3 \rightarrow G^3 \rightarrow G^2 \rightarrow G \rightarrow 0$.

Comment: Which exercise is this? I cannot find it in the exercises after the cellular homology section.

Comment: @MikeMiller Exercise 1 on pg 280 Hatcher Section 3.A

Comment: While I agree the wording is odd I find it very difficult to believe he didn't intend for you to use the Kunneth formula.

Comment: Since the boundary maps for the projective space are so simple isn't it possible to do it without the Kunneth formula?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I've computed the case for when $G = \mathbb{Z}_2$. We simply get if  $ 0 \leq i \leq n$ $H_i(\mathbb{RP}_m \times \mathbb{RP}_n) = \mathbb{Z}^{i+1}$, if $ n \leq i \leq m$ $H_i(\mathbb{RP}_m \times \mathbb{RP}_n) = \mathbb{Z}^{n+1}$, if $ m \leq i \leq n + m$ $H_i(\mathbb{RP}_m \times \mathbb{RP}_n) = \mathbb{Z}^{n+m+1-i}$ and $0$ otherwise.

The case where $G = \mathbb{Z}$ on the other hand has me stumped. I'm reduced to computing homologies with Macaulay2 and trying to find a pattern. I can find the homologies myself by hand from the chain complexes I've computed but this is very slow and tedious. Even so the patterns are not immediately obvious to me.

Thoughts?